# Android Dropbox Auth screen used to be intent, now webpage?

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent, authorization, dropbox

I had been working on dropbox enabling an application and when the person elected to connect to Dropbox, the authentication process launched an intent within the app, once the window popped I was able to accept the access and the app resumed as usual and everything was great.

Something changed when I turned the code over for implementation such that now when I elect to connect to Dropbox, the app instead launches a webpage for authentication instead of the intent.  Also, the "resume" is not called in the application after I authorize the app to dropbox.

I have looked in the usual places but have been unable to determine why this has changed.. Thoughts??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you recently pick up an updated version of the Dropbox SDK?  There was a recent update which uses an improved authorization flow.  If your app is using the new flow, and you don't yet have a version of the Dropbox Android app which supports that flow, then your API app will fall back to using browser-based authorization.  This should go away once the Dropbox Android app is updated in Google Play.

The web-auth flow should still return control to your app in the same way as the delegated-auth flow.  If you're seeing issues there, you should get in touch with Dropbox support.  You can submit a ticket using the "API Support" link on dropbox.com/developers

Comment: That was the answer..  I was running an old version of the Dropbox app on my tablet. - THX